# Xamarin.Forms: Exchange view in container

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, containers, xamarin.forms, master-detail

I've created some pages

```cs
this.content1 = new DetailPage("ContentPage1");
this.content2 = new DetailPage("ContentPage2");
```

and I have defined a field

```cs
private View detailView;
```

with the following layout

```cs
Content = new StackLayout
{
    Padding = new Thickness(0, Device.OnPlatform<int>(20, 0, 0), 0, 0),
    Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
    Children = {
        buttonContainer,
        this.detailView,
    },
};
```

On a button click the `detailView` should be exchanged

```cs
private void Button1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.detailView = this.content1.Content;
}
```

The click event is called, but the view isn't updated. Is this the wrong way to exchange a "subview" in a container? How is this done?

Comment: Whats the default value of `detailview`? Could this be a simple typo where you have used `this.detailView = this.content1.Content;` it should be `this.detailView = this.content2.Content;`?

Comment: 'content1.Content' is default. I have multiple buttons with different content, but the 'detailView' is always 'content1'. No typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the current detailView from the Children collection and then add your new view afterward. Simply swapping the value of detailView will not affect the visual UI.

If I am understanding the context of your code snippets correctly, then this should resolve the problem in your `Button1_Clicked` handler:

```cs
((StackLayout) Content).Children.Remove(this.detailView);
this.detailView = this.content1.Content;
((StackLayout) Content).Children.Add(this.detailView);
```

Comment: There should not be anything to worry about with regards to memory management as long as you are aware that this code keeps all of those detail pages in memory all of the time due to the content1/content2 member fields.

You could define them as Lazy<DetailPage> instead, which would defer construction/allocation until they actually get used. But other than that, there probably isn't anything to be overtly concerned about.

That doesn't necessarily mean that your actual code doesn't have memory leaks - but this code as-is doesn't look nefarious.